# Rotate a grid of points in C++

Tags: c++, math, rotation, grid, geometry

If i had an array of point structs defined as

```
struct Point{

    float x;
    float y;

};
```

How would I rotate the points in this array by a given angle?

As an example:

[image: Example]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: More of a math question, but you should use a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).

Comment: @MooseBoys Could you post some example code for the please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float x_old = p.x; float y_old = p.y;
p.x = x_old * cos(a) - y_old * sin(a);
p.y = x_old * sin(a) + y_old * cos(a);
```

Of course, if you are rotating many points by the same angle, you will want to save the sin & cos, instead of calculating them twice per point.